# UK visa application after Australia refusal for not revealing overstay in the US

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, deception

Could someone please help me understand? I got the UK visa last year, and visited the UK 2 times without any problem. In that application I didn't tell them that I overstayed in the USA from 2006-2012.

My UK visa has expired. In this comming application, I will have to tell them about my overstay. Will the visa officer pull up the previous application to compare with new application? Will the previous application where I got the visa last year affect me for giving false or misleading information and will I get banned for 10 years?

I just got caught by Australia and got a visa refusal, since they share information with each other. I have to disclose my overstay in the USA for the new UK visa application.

Comment: Why did you not tell the UK about your overstay in your last application? Did they ask? What is different this time that you 'have to tell them' where you say you didn't have to before?

Comment: Because there are no question about Have you ever overstayed in any country. It has only have u ever get deported , refused to entry  , forced to leave ....

Comment: This time i got  Australia Visa refusal. I have to give the information why I got refused in the UK application . The reason is about that i lie about the overstay in the USA.

Comment: If i apply for the new UK visa , will I be in trouble ? Because I didnt tell them about the overstayed in the USA in the previous application , so that i might get a 10 years ban .

Comment: Why are you responding to your own comments, you have 3 in a row. Did you lie or didn't you. You said ".. there are no question about Have you ever overstayed.." sounds like your were truthful. Then you said "The reason is about that i lie..".

Comment: @KeithLoughnane "no question about have you ever overstayed" refers to the previous UK visa application, while the lie was in the recent Australia visa application. Because the UK asks about visa refusals for other countries, Pat will have to disclose the Australia refusal and its reason.

Answer (score 9):

You are correct in that you need to tell the UK about your Australian visa refusal, and probably the reasons for it. the UK immigration will find out the reasons anyway from Australian immigration.

Whether you get a ban depends on whether you lied on the original application. If they asked about overstays and you didn't tell them about yours, that is deception, and is extremely likely to get you a ban. If they didn't then you may be OK.

These things are complicated. **I strongly recommend you get the opinion of a UK immigration lawyer.** Your future in the UK is on the line.

Just to note that even if you don't get a ban that does not mean your visa renewal will be approved. The UK now has new information about you that is not favourable, and they may decide that you are too high a risk.

Comment: https://www.2morrowexplorer.com/static/assets/source/Screen%20Shot%202560-10-04%20at%203.13.28%20PM.png

Comment: That are the question in the original application. I overstayed in the US , but never get caught . or removed or anything they ask in these question.

Comment: It looks to me like you didn't lie. But I still recommend a lawyer.

Comment: "Your future in the UK is on the line." I'm not sure the asker is proposing to have a "future in the UK"; just to visit a few times.

Answer (score 3):

The UK visit visa application asks about travel history for the previous 10 years. It does not specifically ask about overstaying in either the U.K. or any where else, however it does ask for the date(s) and length of visit for each country you’ve travelled to during that 10 year period. Given the reason for the Australian visa refusal, which as you say you must disclose, UKVI will find out that you overstayed in the US. Whether it affects your application this time may depend on whether you were truthful about your travel dates to the US in your previous U.K. application(s). As others have said, advice from an immigration lawyer is highly advisable before you apply.
Unless you have a compelling reason for wanting to visit the UK, I would seriously reconsider your travel plans.

Comment: I went to the US and overstayed in 2006  which isnt in the last 10 years . It s more than 10 years, that was my thought , when i filled up the application form, or i might missunderstood.

Comment: @Pat Your question reads as if you entered the US in 2006 and left in 2012. That would put the overstay within the last 10 years, to my way of thinking. If I’ve misinterpreted your question, please would you update it to clarify.

Comment: I have traveled to Australia for about 10 times , and in the application form m I put my detail only 3 - 4 times , and there was no more space for me.

Comment: @Pat if there's not enough space in the application, I believe you're supposed to include additional pages.  I think Traveller is correct that they *might* notice that your overstay ended less than 10 years ago, and they might therefore consider that your travel history response was deceptive.  But they might not.  The only way to know for sure is to apply.  If you can afford one, it would be a good idea to engage a good UK immigration lawyer.