# Implication of not disclosing visa refusal in first application

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

What's the implication of not stating a visa refusal In your first application but states your previous refusal in the new application?

It wasn't stated for reason of refusal though. Thinking of reapplying for a UK visitor visa following a refusal this year. Must one include all visa refusal previously even when you were refused with a missing passport? I was refused a US visa in 2010 and 2012 but the passport I used for these applications is missing.

Comment: What does ‘refused with a missing passport’ mean? If a visa application asks about previous refusals (whether from the jurisdiction to which you’re applying and/or to any others), it is imperative to tell the truth. Lying or attempting to conceal a previous refusal will get you a 10 year (possibly lifetime) ban for deception if it’s discovered (on this or any future applications). Your biometric data is held and countries exchange visa data eg VIS in Schengen, and ‘five eyes countries (US, UK, Canada, Australia, New Zealand).

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/130754/uk-visa-application-after-australia-refusal-for-not-revealing-overstay-in-the-us

Comment: @traveller i was refused US visa in 2010 and 2012 . I applied for uk visa this year and was refused by was based on income . My question is I want to travel and want to know if I'm supposed to disclose my refusal in the new application which i didnt disclose in the first application.

Comment: my old passport which is missing is what i used to apply for the visa in 2010 and 2012 which i got refused

Answer (score 2):

If you have been refused a visa in the past then it's you who has been refused, not your passport. It's irrelevant whether you have subsequently changed passport, whatever the reason.

If you have failed to disclose that refusal in a subsequent application you now have a problem. If the country to which you are now applying knows about that refusal but you fail to disclose it they will deny you entry and possibly impose a long ban for deception.

If you do now disclose the previous refusal, the country to which you're applying will want to know why you didn't disclose it before. If you don't have an excellent explanation they will deny you a visa and possibly apply a long ban for deception.

From the tags and your comments it appears that you are applying to the UK, having been previously refused by the US. Those countries share a lot of immigration information. You should assume both countries know everything about your visa history.

Your history of visa refusals coupled with a failure to disclose previous refusals makes your situation complex. You would do well to consider employing a UK lawyer with immigration experience  if you seriously want to visit the UK.

Comment: what do you suggest ?

Comment: See my last paragraph.

Comment: Do you have any in mind ? You can suggest

Comment: You can find a UK solicitor via the [Law Society](https://www.lawsociety.org.uk/).

Answer (score 0):

You lied in your recent UK application when you answered the question about previous visa refusals from any country negatively. The question says “Have you ever been refused...” - it’s quite clear, it’s not time-bound such that an old refusal no longer needs disclosure after the passage of time, and it doesn’t give any extenuating circumstances under which answering ‘No’ when the truthful answer is ‘Yes’ is allowed. The ‘missing’ passport makes absolutely no difference to the requirement to answer all questions truthfully.

The implications are that you have dug yourself a hole without an exit. You must disclose previous refusals or risk being found out eg through biometric data sharing with the US. If you disclose or you don’t but the UK finds out, you’ll automatically be refused under Immigration Rule 320 (7A) https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-9-grounds-for-refusal

Your only hope might be to consult an Immigration lawyer, however this is likely to be very expensive (if you can find one willing to help) and very possibly fruitless. After all, what explanation do you have for knowingly lying? https://www.gov.uk/find-an-immigration-adviser

Comment: Okay I will disclose it in the next application. But must I draw their attention in my next application or just await the outcome? And also it wasn't the reason for my refusal but on income .

Comment: You _must answer the questions truthfully_. As Traveller and Redd Herring point out, you're likely to be seen as having lied in a prior application. That makes your application extremely challenging, and why Traveller and Roddy and Redd Herring and I all think you should consult a UK immigration lawyer and then _follow the lawyer's advice_.

Comment: To be honest . I didnt pay attention to the application form as I only read have you been refused visa to Uk and not the whole phrase or sentence

Comment: I found out my error when i also thought UKVI made a mistake with interpretation . I reviewed my application form and found it i misread the question.

Comment: @Kay jay Sorry, but everyone says that. See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/64097/what-can-i-do-to-lift-a-10-year-ban-for-making-a-mistake-in-my-uk-visa-applicati?